# Finding Domain of a Function with a natural logarithm at the denominator of the fraction

Tags: functions

I have the function:

$y = f(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x}$

The function is undefined for the conditions:

1. a denominator of a fraction being zero.
2. a logarithm being negative or equal to zero.

Hence, is the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
& x \ne 0\\
& x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

and the domain is $\forall x\in\mathbb R: x > 0$

Following the result showed in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain%20of%20f(x)%20%3D%20x%2Fln(x)) the domain is $\forall x\in\mathbb R: x > 1$ or $0 < x < 1$

Comment: I edited my answer after your corrections in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2. a logarithm being negative.

Watch out: you want the *argument* of the logarithm to be positive, not the logarithm itself ($\ln x$ will be negative if $0 < x < 1$, that's not a problem).

So the denominator can't be $0$ which means $\ln x$ can't be zero which means $x$ can't be $1$:
$$\color{blue}{x \ne 1}$$

Secondly, for $\ln x$ to exist, $x$ has to be strictly positive:
$$\color{blue}{x > 0}$$

Combining both conditions yields: $0 < x < 1$ or $x > 1$, or written as a set:
$$x \in (0,1) \cup (1,+\infty)$$

> Hence, is the system:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> & \color{red}{x \ne 0}\\
> & x > 0
> \end{cases}
> $$

Your error is in red; see above: it is $x=1$ that makes the denominator $0$, not $x=0$.